# android decides to take away focus from input fields and hide custom softkeyboard in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have made a custom soft-keyboard by extending `InputMethodService` in android. As `KeyboardView` is no longer supported, the layout of the keyboard is created using `LinearLayout`. The keyboard works as expected. It shows up when tapped into an input field and I can type text with it.

`But the Problem is:`

###### when I changed the device from `portrait to landscape` or `landscape-right to landscape-left and vice-versa` the android system refused to give focus or takes away focus from already focused input. As a result hides the keyboard.

It only happens with this `custom keybaord`. If I switched to other keyboards like `gboard` or `micorsoft swift keyboard` things works fine. So my question is, what might be causing this issue?

`Sample code can be provided if required.`